# Physijs: Apply impulse/force to a specific point in the 3d body

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I have a 3d model that I'd like to apply a force/impulse to, and have the physics engine Physijs apply the appropriate rotational and translational velocity, given the mass distribution of the object.

How could this best be achieved? As far as I can see, it only has methods for setting the rotational velocity, and applying impulse to the body's centre of mass. However, given that objects can collide and produce rotational velocity, I'd have thought it must at least internally have the capability.

If this is asking too much of Physijs, perhaps there's an alternative javascript physics library that would do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that `applyImpulse()` does do what I want as opposed to `applyCentralImpulse()`.